# How to access assets from external packages?

Tags: flutter, assets

Package_A

An image under lib/images/sample_photo.png

Package_B yaml

```
dependencies:
  Package_A:
    path: ../Package_A

assets:
    - packages/images/sample_photo.png
```

When I try to use Image.asset('packages/images/sample_photo.png') on Package_A, it thrown unable to load asset

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.

Package_B yaml

```
dependencies:
  Package_A:
    path: ../Package_A

assets:
    - packages/Package_A/images/sample_photo.png
```

Use

```
Image.asset('packages/Package_A/images/sample_photo.png')
```

instead of

```
Image.asset('packages/images/sample_photo.png')
```

Comment: To ensure it works properly, please do `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` before having fresh build.

Answer (score 0):

```
assets:
    - packages/Package_A/images/sample_photo.png
```

should do what you want when `images/sample_photo.png` is in `Package_A/lib/images/sample_photo.png`.

The docs briefly address this topic in https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started#importing-libraries-from-packages might provide some additional information about how package paths work.

Comment: It's not working when I try to include all the images under 'Package_A/images/'
`packages/Package_A/images/`, I need to specify each of the image

Comment: Specifying a folder only includes the files directly in that folder, but ignores subfolders (except folders like `2.0x`, `3.0x`, ... for different resolutions of assets in the specified folder). You need to list each folder individually that contain asset files. If that doesn't work for assets in dependency packages, please create a bug report.